# Unwanted spacing with css display and table-cell

Tags: html, css

I am having difficulties in understanding the nature of table and table-cell when used in css.

Consider the following: http://jsfiddle.net/dd7h7/3/.

**HTML**

```
<div class="widget">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="icon">A</div>
      <div class="label">ABC</div>            
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="icon">B</div>
      <div class="label">ABCDEF</div>            
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="icon">C</div>
      <div class="label">ABCDEFGHI</div>            
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.widget {
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.button {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.content {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;    
}

.icon {
    display:table-cell;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}

.label {
    display:table-cell;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    padding-left:3px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Im trying to make a widget containing some buttons, that are positioned alongside each other. But I don't understand where the space between the red boxes comes from. How do I get rid of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inline elements (in your case the .button divs) are sensitive to white space, you can get rid of that space in a variety of ways, including:

- Removing the space between the elements
- Using HTML comments (`<!-- -->`) to occupy the gap
- Floating the elements left

**Example of removing the white space between elements:**

```
<div class="widget">
    <div class="button">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="icon">A</div>
            <div class="label">ABC</div>
        </div>
    </div><div class="button">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="icon">B</div>
            <div class="label">ABCDEF</div>
        </div>
    </div><div class="button">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="icon">C</div>
            <div class="label">ABCDEFGHI</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dd7h7/4/)**

---

**Example of using HTML comments:**

```
<div class="widget">
    <div class="button">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="icon">A</div>
            <div class="label">ABC</div>
        </div>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="button">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="icon">B</div>
            <div class="label">ABCDEF</div>
        </div>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="button">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="icon">C</div>
            <div class="label">ABCDEFGHI</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/R6BGq/)**

---

**Example of using float:**

```
.button {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vJVDT/)**

So in short this really doesn't have to do with display:table-cell but everything to do with display:inline and inline-block.

Answer (score 1):

in this fiddle i removed the space simply using

```
float:left;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dd7h7/5/

Answer (score 1):

inline-block is adding that unnecessary space.
You can do a little trick with font size:

```
.widget {
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size: 0;
}

.button {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add

```
float:left
```

to

```
.button
```

so CSS should be like this

```
.button {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  float: left;
}
```

Hope, that will help. :)